# Fluid simulation not fluid: no liquids coming from inflow or dropping from geometry

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am attempting to make a not-so-accurate tsunami from a flipper in my scene and water.

I have watched hours of YouTube videos on Blender fluid simulations.

The scene is from a mesh created by BlenderGIS and was extruded. I looked at bathymetric data and created the ocean depths around Dingalan Bay, the Philippines.

From the ocean floor, I created an extruded mesh to represent the water (my custom fluid object).

1. I created a `Domain` cube and set it to the appropriate settings according to the videos.
2. I created a little flipper to simulate an earthquake on the ocean floor and animated it to rotate.
3. I made the land mesh an `Effector` and turned up the `Surface Thickness`.
4. I made the custom liquid object into a `Flow Type` of `Liquid` and `Behavior` as `Geometry`.
5. And then I `Baked` `All`.

Nothing worked as I think it should have; consequently, I made a cube into a fluid object, set it above the land mass, and set it to be (a) `Flow Behavior` as `Geometry` and when that did not work, I set it to be (b) `Flow Behavior` as `Inflow`.

Again, no liquids come from the fluid object. The flipper animation works great.

I am including the Blend file to see if anyone can help me determine what I have done wrong.

[image]

[image: no water for Edward]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a big problem with your size and your resolution.

[image]

The orange box in one edge of your domain is the smallest fluid unit. Blender doesn't take into account anything which is smaller than that. So if this is bigger than your inflow or geometry, you won't see anything happen.

So either your crank up your resolution a lot (which makes the fluid simulation incredible slow) or your lower down the size of your domain (which is insane big in your case :8 km x 5km x 3 km).